# Edit pipeline but can't save - azure-pipelines.yml does not exist at commit

Tags: azure-pipelines

I created a yaml pipeline and I'm trying to modify it. I click edit on the pipeline and make a change to the azure-pipelines.yml file but when I save it I get this message.

The path 'DW\src\azure-pipelines.yml' does not exist at commit 'fd621a5009f88684f70d4449467a78050884e7bc'

I have selected "Commit directly to the azure-pipelines branch".

The file does exist and I can edit it by going to Repos/Files and finding it there.

The file is in a sub-folder because I have multiple solutions in the same repo and want separate pipelines for each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. In Pipeline settings I had the YAML file path set to DW\src\azure-pipelines.yml. I changed it to DW/src/azure-pipelines.yml and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Where did you find pipeline settings?  My pipeline yml and repo yml are out-of-sync and I feel like this may be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the branch you modified in the pipeline is consistent with the branch with the `azure-pipelines.yml` file in the repo.

[image]

[image]